# How could I create a string pattern in Lua to find encapsulated text similar to markdown?

Tags: string, lua

I'm still getting used to the concept of string patterns, and I've run into an issue regarding them. I'm trying to create a simple program that searches a string of text, for certain characters encapsulated in whatever the brackets may be. Here's an example:

```
local str = "Hello <<world>>, my <<name>> is <<John>>"

-- Match patterns with << ... >>
for noun in str:gmatch("<<.->>") do
    print(noun)
end
```

This program will search through the string, matching everything that starts with `<<` and ends with `>>`, and everything in between. Good, that's what I want. However, let's say I wanted a different pattern that only got text between one of those tags instead of two (`<` and `>` instead of `<<` and `>>`). This is where I run into a problem:

```
-- Allow easy customization control over brackets
local matchNouns = {"<<", ">>"}
local matchOther = {"<", ">"}

local str = "<Hello> <<world>>, <my> <<name>> <is> <<John>>"

local function printOtherMatches(str)
    -- Get opening and closing brackets
    local open, close = unpack(matchOther)

    -- Concatenate opening and closing brackets with
    -- pattern for finding all characters in between them
    for other in str:gmatch(open .. ".-" .. close) do
        print(other)
    end
end

printOtherMatches(str)
```

The program above *will* print everything between `<` and `>` (the `matchOther` elements), however it also prints text captured with `<<` and `>>` as well. I *only* want the iterator to return patterns that *explicitly* match the opening and closing tags. So the output from above **should print:**

`<Hello>`

`<my>`

`<is>`

**Instead of:**

`<Hello>`

`<<world>>`

`<my>`

`<<name>>`

`<is>`

`<<John>>`

Basically, just like with markdown how you can use `*` and `**` for different formats, I'd like to create a string pattern for that in Lua. This was my attempt of emulating that kind of pattern sequence. If anyone has any ideas, or insight on how I could achieve this, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps, a frontier pattern is what you need: `local matchOther = {"%f[<]<%f[^<]", "%f[>]>%f[^>]"}`, check https://ideone.com/Wf2QQS.

Comment: Does it work as expected, or do you think that does not fit the scenario?

Comment: I'm curious, do you need to account for all characters between the < and >, or can we be specific (only letters)? And do we know if there will always be spaces before and after each tag as given in your example? For example, I likely would solve your example by taking both into account and using the following: for other in str:gmatch('%s?<%a+>%s') do print(other)
end That said, I'm not sure this will account for all scenarios you're looking for, can you provide more information?

Comment: Yeah, that actually did. I didn't know about the %f magic character, but I'll do some experimenting with it.

Comment: See Egor's answer, it might be more comprehensive. If you prefer my solution, I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Allow easy customization control over brackets
local matchNouns = {"<<", ">>"}
local matchOther = {"<", ">"}
local delimiter_symbols = "<>"  -- Gather all the symbols from all possible delimiters above

local function printMatches(str, match_open_close)
   -- Get opening and closing brackets
   local open, close = unpack(match_open_close)
   -- Concatenate opening and closing brackets with
   -- pattern for finding all characters in between them
   for other in str:gmatch(
      "%f["..delimiter_symbols:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."]"
      ..open:gsub("%p", "%%%0")
      .."%f[^"..delimiter_symbols:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."]"
      .."(.-)"
      .."%f["..delimiter_symbols:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."]"
      ..close:gsub("%p", "%%%0")
      .."%f[^"..delimiter_symbols:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."]"
   ) do
      print(other)
   end
end

local str = "<Hello> <<world>>, <my> <<name>> <is> <<John>>"
printMatches(str, matchOther)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
local s = '<Hello> <<world>>, <my> <<name>> <is> <<John>>'

for s in s:gmatch '%b<>' do
  if not s:sub(2,-2):match '%b<>' then print(s) end
end
```

Comment: Actually, it does get matched correctly as `%b<>` counts the number of opening and closing delimiters.  (The b stands for 'balanced')